# Add new fields dynamically to an existing Form Panel

Tags: extjs4.1

I want to add new fields placed inside a container ( layout:hbox ) to the FormPanel dynamically by dragging and dropping.

While dropping in Form panel I'm able to add fields dynamically. 
But i want to add in the position where they dropped.

```
var dynamicField = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container',{
                            layout : 'hbox',

                             items: [{
                                                                xtype:'textfield',
                                                                fieldLable:'Test'

                                                           }, {
                                     xtype : 'image',
                                     src : 'images/cancel.png',
                                     hidden : true

                                  }]
                                      });


                          formPanel.add(dynamicField);

                               //   tried    dynamicField.showAt(e.getXY());
```

with dynamicField.showAt(e.getXY()) no luck //e is the event object

Can anybody suggest me how can i achieve?

Regards
URL

Comment: One idea to resolve this is like, you need to place multiple place holders(droppable containers) inside form panel, so you can replace the container with the newly placed control.

Comment: How can i get the control and position of it? @Rency

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample example for this provided by sencha, http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/dd/dragdropzones.html.   In this we are creating a custom drop-able area and we can add anything to that. check code of this sample.

```
 onNodeDrop : function(target, dd, e, data){
        var rowBody = Ext.fly(target).findParent('.x-grid-rowbody-tr', null, false),
            mainRow = rowBody.previousSibling,
            h = gridView.getRecord(mainRow),
            targetEl = Ext.get(target);

        targetEl.insert(<your control>); // here we can add control directly into it.
        return true;
    }
```

For understanding drag & drop , there is a good guide : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/drag_and_drop